# How do I modify a SELECT query to force specific values to be returned for a column, without updating what's actually stored in the table?

Tags: oracle

I don't know if this is possible, but hopefully this is pretty simply to answer.
Lets say you have read only access to a database (Oracle 11g in this case). You are querying data into an Excel sheet. Part of the data I'm gathering is a panel_name. And I'm only concerned about the data when panel_id=1 OR panel_id=2 OR panel_id=3.

Now, the problem is that for the purposes of this particular query I want to treat panel_id 1 and 3 as if they were the same, not updating the DB, just in the report. So Instead of;

```
when panel_id=1 then panel_name="Panel 1"
when Panel_id=3 then panel_name="Panel 3"
```

I'd like override it so that;

```
when panel_id=1 then panel_name="Panel 1"
when panel_id=3 then panel_name="Panel 1"
```

I haven't found anything that would allow me to do this though. I'm open to other alternatives as well, but in the end I'd just like to have both of those panels be treated as if they were the same. The code looks something like this;

```
SELECT
  requisitions.received_date AS "Received Date"
  ,panels.PANEL_NAME AS "Panel Name"
FROM requisitions

inner join panels ON requisitions.PANEL_ID = panels.PANEL_ID

WHERE (panels.PANEL_ID = 1 OR panels.PANEL_ID = 2 OR panels.PANEL_ID = 3)
ORDER BY requisitions.RECEIVED_DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want to have a `CASE` statement in your query?

```
SELECT
  requisitions.received_date AS "Received Date"
 ,(CASE WHEN panels.panel_id IN (1,3)
        THEN 'Panel 1'
        ELSE panels.PANEL_NAME
    END) AS "Panel Name"
```

If that is not what you're asking, it would be very helpful to post some sample data and the expected output of your query.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it will work! You hit it right on the mark!